# Texture displays on one phone but not other

Tags: android

Hi this is driving me mad, on one phone & emulator texture displays fine on another phone I get the white box! Any ideas why this might be? I have messed about with the bit depth of my png image but not joy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my phone would not assets which were not factors of two. I.e. The sprite can be any size but it MUST come from an asset which has a resoloution which is a factor of two.